# Direct evaluation of a series from Euler's identity.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, pi

Is there a direct way to evaluate:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \dfrac{\pi^{2k}}{(2k)!}=-1
$$

Note that this follows from Euler's identity.

Comment: This is just $\cos \pi = -1$. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Do you want a geometric proof? (That'd be hard.)

Comment: Depends on how you define $\pi$, but it can be a direct consequence of a definition: "$\pi/2$ is the smallest positive root of the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$", plus addition (or duplication) formula, that can be proved with Cauchy product of series.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \dfrac{\pi^{2k}}{(2k)!}=1-\frac{\pi^2}{2!}+\frac{\pi^4}{4!}-\frac{\pi^6}{6!}\cdots$$
$$\cos(\pi)=1-\frac{\pi^2}{2!}+\frac{\pi^4}{4!}-\frac{\pi^6}{6!}\cdots=-1$$

Comment: Don't you mean $\cosh(i\pi)=\cos(\pi)=\dotsb$?

Comment: @columbus8myhw yes

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\sum(-1)^k \frac{\pi^{2k}}{(2k)!}
&= \sum (i)^{2k} \frac{\pi^{2k}}{(2k)!}\\
& = \sum\frac{(i\pi)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\\
& = e^{i\pi}\\ &= -1
\end{align}$$
Due to Euler's identity i.e. $e^{i\pi}+1=0,$ where $e^{i\pi}=cos\pi+i sin\pi=-1.$